# jquery accordion cookie / persistence

Tags: jquery, cookies, persistence, accordion

i want to save the state (open/closed) of an accordion menu with jquery.cookie. 
Could someone help me to set the cookie?

```
$('#menu').children('[data-header]').hide().each(function() {
    $(this).before('<h3 class="menu-header">' + $(this).data('header') + '</h3>');
}).prev().on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on').next().slideToggle();
  });
```

Comment: Do you want this data to persist over different page loads? If so, use a server-side language like PHP. If you only want the data to persist for the page, use variables with global scope

Comment: Please make the feedle on http://jsfiddle.net and post link here

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved here: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/EDQn9/12/
thanks to Hompimpa from css-tricks.com